# Make a method the value of a data property in Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the `euvl/vue-js-modal` package to create a modal in VueJs. I have passed a `question object` to the modal and accepted it using the `@before-open` property. I can get the contents I want by doing

```
methods: {
  beforeOpen(event) {
    console.log(event.params.question.question_body);
  }
}
```

I have a this data property

```
data() {
  return {
    question_body: '',
  }
}
```

How can I get the `question_body` from the `beforeOpen` method to be the value of the `question_body` data property?

If I need to explain myself more please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: So you need to pass `question_body` from somewhere? Can you show method for open your modal?

Comment: `<a href="" @click.prevent="$modal.show('edit-question', { question: {{ $question }} })">edit</a>` Is this what you want?

Comment: So what is your question? Did you get `question_body` in your console? Can you provide more code?

Comment: my question is: How can I get the `question_body` from the `beforeOpen` method to be the value of the `question_body` data property?

Comment: `data() {
      return {
        question_body: beforeOpen,

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: `this.question_body = event.params.question.question_body` like that?

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you! If you want to submit that as an answer I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
this.question_body = event.params.question.question_body
```